# Dropdown Menu Positioning Within Navigation

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am having issues with the positioning of the dropdown menu I’m trying to make on my “Projects” link in my websites header.

I’d like the “Projects” link to stay put and have the dropdown menu open below it and centered. I partly achieved this by attempting to make the dropdownContent div absolutely positioned,  but then the menu is not centered under the “Projects” link.

I am attempting to use flex box for the first time as it is much more intuitive for positioning purposes, but that may be the source of this error.

The HTML/CSS in question:

```
#dropdownContent{
  display:none;
}

#dropdownContent a{
  color: #96C0CE;
  border-right: 1px white solid;
  padding-right: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

#dropdownContent #tutoring{
  border: none;
}

#dropdownContent a:hover{
  color: #525564; 
}

#dropdown:hover #dropdownContent{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

<li class="navlink">
<div id="dropdown">
            <a id="menuTab" href="#">
             Projects
             <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
              </a>
                          <div id="dropdownContent">
                            <a href="#">Engineering</a>
                            <a href="#">Development</a>
                            <a id="tutoring" href="#">Tutoring</a>
                          </div>
             </div>
</li>
```

Codepen is here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oaZLYe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
#dropdown {
  position: relative;
}
#dropdownContent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

[should do it](https://codepen.io/andrei-gheorghiu/pen/zmwGqM).

**Note:** touch devices do not have `:hover`, so you might want to also add `:active` to all current selectors using `:hover`.
And you shouldn't count on having an active link on "Projects". The way this problem is solved in modern UI is by splitting the link it two: the actual link part and the dropdown opener (or caret). But the caret should be big enough to accommodate a finger, without the risk of touching the "link" part (standard size is `45px ✕ 45px` but most users can safely use a `35px ✕ 35px` caret).

Comment: Thanks Andrei! I’ve yet to think about mobile devices at this point as I’m still learning fundamentals. I will keep this in mind when I get there!

Answer (score 1):

```
#dropdown {
  position: relative;
}
#dropdownContent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
```